# MetadataType Attribute are being ignored Telerik.AccessData.Core 2016.1.224 fluent mapping

Tags: database, orm, telerik, telerik-mvc, telerik-open-access

I'm developing an asp.net core 1.0 (MVC 6) full framework 4.6.1 and I created a Class Library targeting framework 4.6.1 for Data Modeling using Telerik DataAccess core & fluent 2016.1.224.

I have some classes, one of them is:

```
namespace DataModel 
{
    public partial class Directory
    {
        private int _id;
        public virtual int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this._id;
            }
            set
            {
                this._id = value;
            }
        }

        private string _directoryId;
        public virtual string DirectoryId
        {
            get
            {
                return this._directoryId;
            }
            set
            {
                this._directoryId = value;
            }
        }

        private string _directoryFullName;
        public virtual string DirectoryFullName
        {
            get
            {
                return this._directoryFullName;
            }
            set
            {
                this._directoryFullName = value;
            }
        }
```

I need to customize Dataannotations to set display name & validations for every property. According telerik documentation, I'm declaring another partial class for original generated fluent Directory class to decorate it with MetadataType, like following:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Directory.DirectoryMetadata))]
public partial class Directory
{
    internal sealed class DirectoryMetadata
    {
        public DirectoryMetadata()
        {
        }

        [Display(Name = "Id Directorio")]
        [Required()]
        public string DirectoryId
        { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nombre Completo")]
        [Required()]
        public string DirectoryFullName
        { get; set; }
```

When I run asp.net core app, MetadataType is not working, no display name nor validator works. However, for some reason, decorating original generated fluent class works fine!:

```
public partial class Directory
{
    private int _id;
    public virtual int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            this._id = value;
        }
    }

    private string _directoryId;
    [Display(Name = "Id Directorio")]
    [Required()]
    public virtual string DirectoryId
    {
        get
        {
            return this._directoryId;
        }
        set
        {
            this._directoryId = value;
        }
    }

    private string _directoryFullName;
    [Display(Name = "Nombre Completo")]
    [Required()]
    public virtual string DirectoryFullName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._directoryFullName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._directoryFullName = value;
        }
    }
```

Both classes, Original and metadata are in the same namespace. In fact, declaring Directory metadata class into a separate file instead internal doesn't work also.

Please, need your help!

Comment: Can you try with public nested metadata class? This is my first suspect. If it does not help check if your partial pieces are properly stitched together using decompilation tool (like JustDecompile)

Comment: Hi ViktorZ, using nested public class for metadata as you proposed not works, not even as public partial class. Looking at by using JustDecompile, it shows public class metadata into original class Directory, and on top of class Directory decorated with MetadataType. However it doesn't work. On other hand, having metadata as a separated class, I mean, not nested, it doesn't work either, JustDecompile shows it well. I've read some site that in Core is used ModelMetadataDetailsProvider but I don't know how to use it, however ¿How is it possible that using original class decorated works fine?

Comment: Also is commented in internet that ModelMetadataTypeAttribute is replacing MetadataTypeAttribute however last one still is used because decorating original class works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it could be due to my main project is asp.net core 1.0 (MC6) full framework 4.6.1 and class library is an estandar dll targeting 4.6.1 and is referenced from main project as project instead dll? I don't know

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution by myself.

For Asp.Net core projects I had to use **ModelMetadataTypeAttribute** instead of **MetadataTypeAttribute** from **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core** assembly. Decorating a metadata class (buddy class) follows same methodology of using Display(...), DisplayName(...), same for validators. No matter if the buddy class (Metadata Class) is located external from or internal to the model class.

However using MetadataTypeAttribute directly with the model class instead of a buddy class, works perfectly!

The only explanation I could give about this divergence is related with the new emerging Microsoft Asp.Net core technology, relocation of DLL process and functionalities.

Comment: Hi, i cant´t get my validations working with ModelMetadataType. This was working in MVC5. It just doesn't work with my validations in MVC6. Can you help me o show how your validations work? Thanks!!

Comment: Snekkke, As far as I know, MetadataTypeAttribute is the regular form to decorate model class before MVC6. Since ASP.NET Core 1.0, way to do it changed a little by using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core namespace, so the steps I followed was: I created a class library for store model class, I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core assembly to before mentioned project. Original model class kept with no decorating due to I'm using an ORM tool that generates model classes automatically and can loose any changes

Comment: So I created a buddy class for decorating, e.g: ORM generated class: namespace Iridium.BackendCore 
{
 public partial class Usuario
 {
  private string _id;
  public virtual string Id
  {
   get
   {
    return this._id;
   }
   set
   {
    this._id = value;
   }
  }
etc.,

Comment: Buddy Class: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Iridium.BackendCore
{
    [ModelMetadataType(typeof(UsuarioMetadata))]
    public partial class Usuario
    {
        internal sealed class UsuarioMetadata
        {
            [Display(Name = "Id Usuario")]
            [Required()]
            public string IdUsuario
            { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Clave")]
            [Required()]
            public string Clave
            { get; set; }
        }
    }
}

Comment: Important! After declaring validation, you have to add <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script> and after it, <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script> to make validation works, otherwise class and tags that Microsoft add dynamically to controls, won't have effect. That's it for me!